# Python 'ast' module with Visitor pattern - get node's group, not concrete class

Tags: python, visitor-pattern

I'm using `ast` python library and want to traverse through my ast nodes.

Visitor pattern is supported in the library pretty well, but if I use it, I will have to implement methods for visiting items of concrete classes, e.g. `def visit_Load`. In my case, concrete classes are not so important - I'd like to know whether the node is an `operator` or an `expr` according to the structure given [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar).

Of course, I can add `generic_visit` method and then check all the conditions here, but that looks like a wrong way to use the pattern.

Is there any other pretty way to implement this idea without massive code duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't pretty, but you can dynamically create all the methods by introspection:

```
def visit_expr(self, node):
    """Do something in here!"""
    self.generic_visit(node)

ExprVisitor = type('ExprVisitor', (ast.NodeVisitor,), {
    'visit_' % cls.__name__: visit_expr for cls in ast.expr.__subclasses__()})
```

Of course, you can keep doing this for whatever ast node types you need to deal with. . .

Comment: That's not really pretty indeed, but, anyway, thank you for that. That solves the problem.